# Time Signature in Prophecy

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches

Does anyone know of any written material on Time Signature in Bible Prophecy? What are the rules for interpreting these time signatures?  Coming from the Sevent-day Adventist  background the rule is day-year in every time signature.  While I am partial to the day-year the bible does not say that.  It is William Miller's rule for interpretation.  Dr. Clearance Hewitt of the Advent Christian Church another Adventist branch lay down some rule in his dissertation on Daniel "the Seer of Babylon"  where he gives a few more rules for interpretation,  including favoring internal textal evidence from the chapter and book rather then importing from an external chapter and book.

Let me give you an example.  The 2300 days of Daniel 8. is a very debated topic.  There are people that interpret the 2300 days as literal years, leading to 2300 years. There are other who interpret it as 1150 year or half the time.  In either case you are left with some person using an outside source to interpret the text rather then relying on what the text says, which is 2300 evenings & mornings, which is the same as Genesis 1.  In both cases there is no rule and no evidence has been presented for adding years or cutting day in half.  Can anyone solve this problem.

Does anyone know of anyother rules for interpretation that have been handed down from history.  Either Jewish or Christian?

Comment: @ Surfmonkey707 - A good rule of thumb in hermeneutics is to see if the plain reading does have a specific fulfilment in history, without stretching the meaning of the dates. And in this case, yes, this prophecy was fulfilled ! Again, stating a Day as two halves was common in the Old Testament. All the other year-day time periods in this chapter which are manipulated to describe European history are pure speculation. Daniel's inspired prophecy was fulfilled accurately.

Comment: @raygrant  while I respect your opinion.  I am not sure that 1150 is the right answer.  I think there is more there.  There is nothing that says cut it in half.  the 1150 does not exactly fit. Antiochus did not go away after 1150 days.

Comment: @ Surfmonkey707 - Sorry that you mistake my wording. I am not advocating 1150! The number 2300 stands. It's just that the Bible has a custom of describing **one day** poetically using wording about two events: mornings and evening...days and nights...etc.  There is no "cutting in half."  The event described prophetically was 2300 full days.  (Not quite 6 1/2 years.)   The practice of interpreting this as 2300 years, or the practice of dividing to mean 1150 days are both unnecessary.  History bears out the 2300 days. Sorry about the confusion. Your interest in  Bible is refreshing; keep it up.

Comment: I find it peculiar that the WW2 sea battle between Japan and the US, approximately halfway through the war, occurred at a place called 'Midway'. Strange coincidence, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The year-for-day principle states that for most Bible prophecies that have time elements, prophetic days should be understood as literal years.  This idea is very ancient and has been used by conservative theologians, including the Jews.

Biblically, this idea rests on several lines of evidence.

**Explicit**:  Num 14:34, Eze 4:5, 6.

**Almost Explicit**:  The 70 weeks prophecy of Daniel 9 is understood my most to be a time prophecy of Messiah and thus the 70 weeks are 490 days (there are several ways this has been understood but all involve the year-for-day idea).

**Implicit**:

- Isa 34:8 - For the LORD has a **day** of vengeance, a **year** of recompense for the cause of Zion.
- Isa 61:2 - to proclaim the **year** of the LORD’s favor and the **day** of our God’s vengeance, to comfort all who mourn
- Isa 63:4 - to proclaim the **year** of the LORD’s favor and the **day** of our God’s vengeance, to comfort all who mourn,
- Job 10:5 - Are Your **days** like those of a mortal, or Your **years** like those of a man,
- Job 36:11 - If they obey and serve Him, then they end their **days** in prosperity and their **years** in happiness.
- See also Ps 39:5, 61:6, 90:10, 15, Eze 22:4, etc.  All these references use “year” and “day” interchangeably in the Hebrew, usually in Hebrew parallelism.  Here are a few more examples:
- Numerous references in the Genesis 5 genealogies have the oft repeated formula, “And all the days of xxx were yyy years…” etc, more than 20 times in this chapter alone.
- Ex 13:10 – The Passover was to be observed “from days to days” clearly meaning “year after year” as most versions correctly have it
- Judges 17:10 - And Micah said to him, “Stay with me, and be to me a father and a priest, and I will give you ten pieces of silver per year and a suit of clothes and your living.” And the Levite went in. [The "year" here is actually “day”.]
- Lev 25:29 - “If a man sells a dwelling house in a walled city, he may redeem it within a year of its sale. For a full year he shall have the right of redemption. ["year" here is actually, “day”.]
- 1 Sam 2:19 – Hannah took Samuel a new robe “from days to days” clearly meaning “year after year”, or, “each year” as most versions correctly have it.
- 1 Sam 20:6 – David asked to be excused from the “sacrifice of the days” clearly meaning “annual sacrifice” as most versions correctly have it.
- 1 Sam 27:7 – David dwelt in the land of the Philistines “days and four months” clearly meaning “a year and four months” as most versions correctly have it.

Now, none of this is iron-clad proof that the year-day principle is valid for many Bible prophecies; however, as asked by the OP, this is the Biblical material on which it rests.

Comment: I am very familiar with the day-year principle.  But there is a problem with your response.  The 70 weeks can be understood without the day-year.  It states in the text that you are counting years, in groups of 7, not day-years. for the 2300 day, it says evenings & mornings not years.   While there is precedent for using a day year in some texts, to say it is universal and applies in all-time prophecy is overdoing it. If you are going to say it applies in the 2300 days or the 1290 or 1335 there should be something in the text that tells us that.

Comment: @MarshallAckerman - that is not quite true.  The prophecy says that there would be seventy weeks, ie, 70 groups of seven day.  years and never mentioned at all.

Comment: @ Marshall Ackerman - The word in Daniel 9 is "heptads" and could refer to any group of seven. The KJV is misleading in using "week". That it means, in this case, 7 groups of years is determined by the context...and ultimately by the awesome fulfilment in the appearance of Christ.  The Magi, who were from Daniel's territory, no doubt interpreted this in this way.  And it was an expectation among the Jews in the first century that the Kingdom of God was about to come, as even the Roman writers noted, based on this calculation of years, not day-years.---the best rule in herm. is "context" .

Comment: @raygrant,  I agree with you concerning the "heptads".  To be more precise, the context concerns what Jeremiah said in 2 Chronicles 36:21 "To fulfill the word of the LORD by the mouth of Jeremiah, until the land had enjoyed her sabbaths: for as long as she lay desolate she kept sabbath, to fulfill threescore and ten years.  Notice the context is Sabbath years. Sabbath years are counted every 7 years.  70 Sabbath * 7 years = 490 years. Repeated in the 70 weeks, it equals 490 years and no day-year is used. so the day-year is not universal and does not apply in every time prophecy.

Comment: @raygrant - apart from this passage in Dan 9:24-27, can you point out another place where שְׁבוּעַ means anything other than a week of seven days?  Even in Dan 10:2, 3 it means week.

Comment: @Dottard can you tell me what the Jewish sources are?  I would like to read them

Comment: @Surfmonkey707 - I am not sure what you mean by "Jewish sources".  I only quoted the Bible.

Comment: @Dottard you said "This idea is very ancient and has been used by conservative theologians, including the Jews."  What Jews.  please give the source.

Comment: @Dottard, you said that Day & Year are used interchangeably.  Yet in the examples given above, they are not interchangeable they are used simultaneously. Is it your contention that whenever the word day and year are mentioned in the same sentence or paragraph it is an example of the day-year principle?

Comment: @Surfmonkey707 - I said what I said.  Often (not always) "day" and "year" are used in parallel suggesting that one is sometimes used for the other.

Comment: @Dottard OK just wanted to clarify the point.  While I have you here do you have the Jewish sources?

Comment: @Surfmonkey707 - see the Jewish commentary of the 1st and 2nd centuries.

Comment: @Dottard do you have the link and source

Comment: @Surfmonkey707 - no - that was my recollection from seeing it previously.  Plenty available in line.  Search Talmud and Mishnah.

Comment: @Dottard i will start there,

Comment: @Dottard,  the word used in daniel is Shavium it refers to Sabbath Years, Leviticus 25:8  To understand this chapter we must begin with an explanation of the term “weeks.”

Daniel chapter 9 uses the Hebrew word (שבעים ~ Shavuim) to represents a period of time multiplied by seven. For various reasons this word is translated as “weeks” and means a multiple of seven years rather than a multiple of seven days.

Comment: @Dottard, a) We see a similar use in the verse, “You shall count~ שבע שבתת השנים) seven Shabbaths of years), seven years seven times… forty-nine years.” Leviticus 25:8
b) A Shabbath is a period of seven days and shares the same Hebrew root for the word
c) Normally the plural of week would be (שבעות ~ Shavuot) in Daniel it uses the masculine “ים” ending for ( שבעים~ Shavuim) similar to (years ~ שנים) This indicates that (שבעים~ Shavuim) is referring to a multiple of seven years
d) Both Jews and Christians agree that this is referring to a multiple of years.

Comment: @Surfmonkey707 - that is factually incorrect.  The word in Dan 9:24 is שְׁבוּעַ (the ordinary word for week) while that in Lev 25:8 is שֶׁבַע the ordinary word for seven.  They are different words.

Comment: @Dottard you are wrong.  this is the word שָׁבֻעִ֨ים Note the ending it is the same as שָׁנִ֔ים  in 25:8.  you are looking at the wrong word. look at the word years in Leviticus 25:8.

Comment: @Surfmonkey707 - the word for years (which is ordinary word for years) is שָׁנֶה.

Comment: @Dottard  you are correct and that is not the word used in Daniel.  it has a masculine ending which changes the meaning of the word to years.  That was addressed in my post.

Comment: @Dottard,  here is the link to the post i quoted https://jewsforjudaism.org/knowledge/articles/daniel-9-a-true-biblical-interpretation/